# iOS 14.5.1 iPhone 12 Pro GPS loses current location while driving

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps, maps, restart

My iPhone 12 Pro Max (running iOS 14.5.1), and also my partners 12 Pro (running 14.4.2) have both always had the GPS apps working without issues (Maps, Google Maps, Waze, etc). Now out of nowhere here is what happens:

I open Google Maps, it shows the blue dot for current location. I enter in the address and tap 'Start' to start navigation. It announces the first step (e.g drive 100m on Thomas street and turn right at Engine avenue). As I am driving, the blue direction arrow suddenly jumps to another street and slowly rotates as if it is failing to determine my direction.

Out of nowhere a few seconds later it gives a completely wrong directive, based on where it thinks I am located. My partner opens Waze, and enters the same address. Waze says 'No gps signal' at the top of the screen. I open my Waze and see the same message. We both open maps and try navigating using that. It works for a few seconds then the location indicator just freezes in one location while we are moving.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

1.
Go to Settings -> Location -> Turn off -> wait for a few seconds -> Turn on While in location settings, make sure 4g (LTE) is enabled (disabled 5g at some point and enabled it again)
2. Open the apps, drive around. Didn't work. Go to settings -> General -> Reset Network settings -> open Maps -> Enable Use location while using app plus all permissions location related.
3. Allow for specific/precision location when asked. All this didn't work.
4. Soft reset device -> Press volume up, press volume down. Press power button until phone switches off and shows Apple logo.
5. After this the GPS apps seemed to work until today (two days later)where the same annoying behaviour started again.

My partner is having the same issues and her phone is connected to a different carrier network where they have their own towers I believe. So I'm guessing this may have nothing to do with the carrier, but maybe it does.

Does anybody have a clue on how to fix this please? Going to an Apple store is a bit problematic because of my location, and I do not want to fully reset my phone until there are no other options... I would even buy a dedicated GPS device before I fully reset my phone, sadly.

**Update**
I have tried going to Date settings and disabling then again enabling Set Automatically. That did nothing. A normal restart did nothing too unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like this is your car causing the problem. The best course of action would be to identify another car and try with your phones - or find someone who can use GPS in their car and try in yours.

Comment: Interesting suggestion @EzekielElin. I will check that out. Cheers

Comment: @EzekielElin You were right. GPS works 100% when in another car. Dang

Comment: @EzekielElin were there recent changes to GPS antenna power in any of the recent iOS versions maybe?

Comment: No idea, unfortunately 